# Only add form field if it is not null in OkHttp

Tags: java, okhttp

I've been to asked to refactor some code that makes a request to a web API that I have no idea what happens when it receives the request. I just have to clean up the code that makes the request. I now have this:

```
FormBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("task", task.get("task"))
        .add("status", task.get("status"))
        .add("spent_time", task.get("spentTime"))
        .add("impediments", task.get("impediments"))
        .add("reoccurring", String.valueOf(task.get("reoccurring")))
        .build();
return new OkHttpClient().newCall(
        new Request.Builder()
                .url(buildUrl("/activities/" + task.get("id")))
                .method("POST", formBody)
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .build()
```

Originally, this function was split into three more functions.

- One url call for having the forms `task` and `status`
- another url call for having `spent_time` and `impediments`
- and then another url call for only having `reoccurring`

But since they all belong to the same url, I've decided to combine them into one function because I had an idea. Though it seems my idea kinda falls short. How do I make it so that if (e.g.) `task`,`status`, and `reoccurring` are `null`, then it would only create a form that *only has* `spent_time` and `impediments`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `task` variable is a map of some sorts that has String keys and Object values. Here is your solution:

```
Builder builder = new FormBody.Builder();
String[] names = { "task", "status", "reoccurring", "spent_time", "impediments" };
for (String name : names) {
    Object value = task.get(name);
    if (value != null)
        builder.add(name, value instanceof String ? (String) value : String.valueOf(value));
}

FormBody formBody = builder.build();
```

This iterates through all your form keys and checks whether the values are null or not before adding them to your form builder.

If you want you can change this to use [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html), which might be more efficient and shorter.

Comment: Neeto! I thought that FormBody.Builder of okhttp couldn't be instantiated due to package private stuff. My bad for misunderstanding it. With your solution, I'll just be using `bodyBuilder.add(name, String.valueOf(value)` to add it to the builder. Thanks mate!

Comment: @RigoSarmiento no problem. Always happy to help.